# I've given up, missing $ error. Help?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

```
 A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} \iff \emph{ $i\in C, i\to j$ \implies $j$ \in $C$ } \\
```

Overleaf shows this where the error is. I've used my brain to find the error but no progress. Error is - missing $ inserted.

Comment: The error indicates that some math maerial is not in math mode. `\implies` seems not to be, but i didn't test. How are you using the dollar signs right now? They seem to be more or less random.

Comment: It is probably the `\in `. Try `$j \in C$`.

Comment: This compiles: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} $\iff$ 
 $i\in C, i\to j \implies j \in C$ 
\end{document}`.

Comment: If the answer provided below has solved the issues you were facing, please consider upvoting and/or "accepting" it.

Answer (score 13):

The directives `\iff`, `\implies`, and `\in` must all be executed in math mode. Separately, the `\emph` directive does nothing here, since it's a text-mode command whereas its argument consists entirely of math-mode material.

Hence, you need to replace

```
A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} \iff \emph{ $i\in C, i\to j$ \implies $j$ \in $C$ }
```

with

```
A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} $\iff i\in C, i\to j \implies j \in C$.
```

Better still, write

```
A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} if and only if $i\in C, i\to j$ implies $j\in C$.
```

Of course, you may choose to write "iff" instead of "if and only if".

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\implies" macro
\begin{document}
A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} $\iff i\in C, i\to j \implies j \in C$.

A subset $C$ is \emph{closed} iff $i\in C, i\to j$ implies $j\in C$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mavellous! The example at the bottom is (a) more readable, (b) has fewer characters to type, (c) is shorter when typeset. What's not to like?

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Many thanks for your compliment!

Comment: +1 for more words and fewer symbols.